# Register factory function at application initialization

Tags: c#, initialization

For a server I am writing, I have a folder of files, one class in each file.
Each class represent a request action from the client.
If I add a new action, I want to simply be able to add a new file, letting the file register itself.

In language such as [Go](http://golang.org) you can have `init` functions, one in each file, that runs at initialization, letting you register things like factory delegates (or first class functions).

Can you achieve something similar in C#, letting the files register their own classes without you having to edit a second file containing a list of all registered actions?

```
// This won't work, but how to do it?
func init() {
    // Registering a factory function to a Dictionary<string, Func<IAction>>
    Reg.ClassDictionary.Add("connect", () => { return new Connect(); });
}

namespace Action
{
    class Connect : IAction
    {
         [JsonProperty("user")]
        public string Username;

        [JsonProperty("pass")]
        public string Password;

        public bool Exec()
        {
            return ConnectToServer(Username, Password);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What platform is this? Windows service? ASP.NET?

Comment: It is a Windows Console application (but yes, it will be a Windows service later on)

Comment: If it's a console app, just do it at the start of your `Main` method. If it's a windows service, when you extend `ServiceBase`, you get an `OnStart` method you override that executes when the service starts.

Comment: @ChrisSinclair What I ask is how to avoid having a single place like `Main` to register the factory delegates. In Go I can add one `init` function in each file, and all of them will be executed at startup - registering themselves.

Comment: AFAIK, that doesn't exist. But see my edited question for a workaround. I have to run now so I can't go into more detail, but hopefully that'll get your noggin' going.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's a console app, just do it at the start of your `Main` method.

If it's a windows service, when you extend `ServiceBase`, you get an `OnStart` method (that you can override) which executes when the service starts. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.servicebase.onstart.aspx

Here's a quick tutorial on Windows Services to get you started: http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/creating-a-simple-windows-service-in-csharp

EDIT: Based on your clarification, AFAIK, there's no built-in way to have files/types do what you're asking. However, what you could do is some reflection. You can peruse your assemblies for particular types/interfaces that implement your `IAction` (or rather, some other descriptive type). You can search through for all of them, instantiate them, then call their various `init` methods during the startup phases I described above.

Comment: This would unfortunately still require me to have a central place where I list all available actions (in `Main` or in `OnStart`). I want to avoid having to edit `Main` when adding a new file.

Comment: If reflection is required, using the `Main` would probably be a lot less hassle. Thanks for helping me out, clarifying this!

Answer (score 2):

Depends on how your assemblies are organised but here's one way to do that.
Define a custom attribute
Called say MyTask, so you can identify all the classes in the assemblies of interest and the name you want to expose is as e.g. "connect" in your example.

Then use reflection to nip through the assembly, find the chaps you want and register them.

Don't know how much you know about attributes and refelection

but here's one of mine

```
[System.AttributeUsage(System.AttributeTargets.Class, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = true)]
public sealed class ConversionAttribute : System.Attribute
{
    public string DatabaseName { get; set; }
    public bool ReadOnly { get; set; }
    public int ConversionOrder { get; set; }
    public String VersionStart { get; set; }
    public String VersionEnd { get; set; }
}
```

A class is marked up like so

```
[Conversion(ConversionOrder = 14)]
public class ConversionExample : DataConversion
```

And this chap runs throughn the assembly grabbing hold of any marked up with ConversionAttribute, instantiates it and then calls a method.

```
public static void DoConversions()
{
    Type[] contents = CommandLine.Instance.TaskAssembly.GetExportedTypes();
    SortedDictionary<int, List<Type>> conversions = new SortedDictionary<int, List<Type>>();
    foreach (Type t in contents)
    {
        ConversionAttribute attr = FindAttribute(t);
        if (attr != null)
        {
            if (!conversions.ContainsKey(attr.ConversionOrder))
            {
                 conversions.Add(attr.ConversionOrder, new List<Type>());
            }
            conversions[attr.ConversionOrder].Add(t);
        }
    }

    foreach (int order in conversions.Keys)
    {
        foreach (Type t in conversions[order])
        {
            ConstructorInfo c = t.GetConstructor(new Type[] { typeof(CommandLine) });
            DataConversion d = (DataConversion)c.Invoke(new object[] { CommandLine.Instance });
            ConversionVersionStatus status = d.VersionStatus(CommandLine.Instance.TaskParameterValue("TAX_FULL_VERSION"));
            if ((status == ConversionVersionStatus.NoVersionSet) || (status == ConversionVersionStatus.Relevant))
            {
                d.Log(String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "Started Conversion {0}", d.FriendlyName));
                d.ExecuteTask();
                d.Log(String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "Finished Conversion {0}", d.FriendlyName));
           }
           else
           {
               if (status == ConversionVersionStatus.Discontinued)
               {
                   d.Log(String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "Conversion {0} skipped as discontinued", d.FriendlyName));
               }
               else
               {
                   d.Log(String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "Conversion {0} skipped as not yet relevant", d.FriendlyName));
               }
           }
       }
   }
}
```

So basically to add a new task, we define it in the dll, mark it up with that attribute, job done.

After this you are talking some sort of config file, either an explicit one, or going down the DI and service discovery route.

Comment: +1 I think this is similar to what @ChrisSinclair had in mind as a work around, but you actually show how to do it. Good to know that it is possible to do it at least.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a static initializer on the class.

```
namespace Action
{
    class Connect : IAction
    {
        static Connect ()
        {
            Reg.ClassDictionary.Add("connect", () => { return new Connect(); });
        }

        [JsonProperty("user")]
        public string Username;

        [JsonProperty("pass")]
        public string Password;

        public bool Exec()
        {
            return ConnectToServer(Username, Password);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: These would only fire when the type is first accessed. If the type is never hit, the factory/init won't run.

Comment: @ChrisSinclair That is a pity, because this would otherwise be what I am looking for. I will try it out just to be sure! :)

Comment: @ChrisSinclair is correct.  The code will execute when the class is loaded for the first time.  Depending on your scenario that may or may not work for you.

Comment: @JohannStrydom The class will only be accessed through the Dictionary storing the factory delegate; that is the only place the application would be aware of the presence of the class.